# Ionic cannot add android platform

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to add the android platform using the following command

```
ionic platform add android
```

I am presented with the following output:

```
Creating android project...

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'which'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user1/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:27:13)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    Error: /Users/user1/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
        at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

I have set the PATH in my bash_rc file as such:

```
export PATH=/Users/user1/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/user1/android-sdk-macosx/tools:$PATH
```

Adding the iOS platform was simple; no problems there.

I checked my Android SDK and everything seems to be up to date.
I also tried reinstalling cordova with `sudo npm -g uinstall cordova` followed by  `sudo npm -g install cordova`

I have checked that `npm`, `cordova`, and `ionic` have been installed globally.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the directory

```
/Users/user1/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/
```

There should be three modules in this directory, `which`, `shelljs` and `q`. They are part of the cordova-android 3.6.4 release so it is hard to see why one would be missing. If `which` is not there it might be best to remove the android platform and add it again.

```
ionic platform rm android
```

Update after your comment.

I don't think reinstalling the android platform will make any difference. It looks more like a node issue specific to your environment.  The check_reqs script that is failing is run from the

```
/Users/user1/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/lib
```

directory. If you change to this directory then run node interactively you can run then run the command:

`require('which')`

If this fails run:

`module.paths`

which will print out the paths that node used to attempt to find the which module. There should be an entry for

```
/Users/user1/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules
```

which is where the `which` module is.

Comment: It looks like `which` exists in the `3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/` directory. I am contemplating running the `ionic platform rm android` command but I am scared that I won't be able to add the platform back, since that is my problem in the first place.

Comment: Added some more to the answer above. It may give you some clue as to what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem, found that there wasn't "which" folder and its contents in android\cordova\node_modules. Once I copied the which folder from .cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\which 
The build was successful